# firestore recyclerView get field and delete data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I saved the data to the firestore and finished printing on the screen.
I printed out each index using recyclerView.
Each index content has a Delete button and I want to delete the data when I click the Delete button.
However, when you click the Delete button, all documents in the field are deleted.
How do I delete only the index contents where the button is located?

Adapter

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MainViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        Delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                db.collection("medicinday").document(mDataset.get(position).getId())
                        .delete()
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                Toast.makeText(activity,"success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                        }) 
                          ...    
            }
        });
       TextView nameTextView = cardView.findViewById(R.id.name_medicin_text);
       nameTextView.setText(mDataset.get(position).getName());
         ...
```

Activity

```
DocumentReference documentReference = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("medicinday").document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail());
        documentReference.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                    if (document != null) {
                        if (document.exists()) {
                            List list = (List) document.getData().get("add_day");
                            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                                Log.i("TEST", "data[" + i + "] > " + list.get(i).toString());
                                HashMap map = (HashMap) list.get(i);
                                addDayList.add(new AddDayInfo(
                                        map.get("Name").toString(),
                                            ...
                                        document.getId()));
                           }

                      } 
                      ...
```

Comment: this seems to be an issue on how the document ID is passed to get the ID of the document you want to delete.  Could you please log  `position` and `mDataset.get(position).getId()` before they are used on the deletion. This to validate if this is the issue or we need to look somewhere else.

Comment: I tried many things, but I couldn't solve them. Thank you for your comment.